# jquery highlight certain section of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

My team has come to conclusion that in order to highlight certain text we will use !!! as special symbol. Long story.

```
I love !!!JavaScript and jQuery!!!.
```

should get transformed into

```
I love <span class='hl'>JavaScript and jQuery</span>.
```

Do not worry about the edge cases. We are developing a system for school children and they don't have complex text with lots of bangs.

How do I do that?

Bonus question: After the span is applied then I was going to use jQuery higlighter plugin to highlight that code. Any suggestion in that direction.

Comment: why are trying to change this in jQuery? This seems like something that would be handled server-side

Comment: you are right. However because of certain constraints if we can pull it off on client side and then that will save us a lot of time.

Comment: Please provide some more context. Is this a web form? You might want to use Regular Expressions to locate the triple-bang bracketed phrases and replace them. also, instead of naming your css class h1, rather call it something meaningful like "hilite", then you can associate whatever CSS rules with it you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` in Javascript only replaces the first occurrence of a string, so you can put this feature to good use and do this:

```
var mytext = "I love !!!Javascript and jQuery!!!. Ya, !!!jQuery!!! rocks!";

while(true) {
    if (mytext.indexOf('!!!') == -1) break;
    mytext = mytext.replace('!!!', '<span class="hl">');
    mytext = mytext.replace('!!!', '</span>');
}
alert(mytext);
```

Output:
`I love <span class="hl">Javascript and jQuery</span>. Ya, <span class="hl">jQuery</span> rocks!`

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need jQuery for this -- you can do it with javascript's build in string `replace` function:

```
var s = 'I love !!!JavaScript and jQuery!!!. Even with multiple !!!occurrences!!!.';
var replaced = s.replace(/!!!(.+?)!!!/g, function(match, text)
    {
        return '<span class="hl">' + text + '</span>'; 
    }
);
```

This form of the `replace` function accepts a regular expression and a function used to determine the replacement string. The parameters to the function are the full match (eg '!!!Javascript and jQuery!!!'), then each portion of the match that corresponds to each parametrized component of the regular expression (in this case there's only one).

NB (just in case): the `?` in the regular expression makes the `.+` match [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), so that you get this:

```
I love <span class="highlight">JavaScript and jQuery</span>. Even with multiple <span class="highlight">occurrences</span>.
```

instead of this:

```
I love <span class="highlight">JavaScript and jQuery!!!. Even with multiple !!!occurrences</span>.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this problem, you will need the [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) function in jQuery which will select all children of your selector, including text. You can read an example of how someone used it here: [Only select text node without DOM](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/only-select).

The difficulty you're going to have is that you need the odd !!!'s to be replaced with  and the even !!!'s to be replaced with .  Fortunately, jQuery has selectors for [odds](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and [evens](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) which should allow you to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

For a jQuery text highlight plugin you may want to consider http://www.frightanic.com/2011/02/27/lenient-jquery-highlight-plugin-javascript/